# Evaluate Cov(A, BS)

Tags: covariance

Suppose I have three real-valued random variables A, B and S with poisson or negative binomial distribution. Let (⋅) denote the covariance operator. How do I evaluate Cov(B, AS)?

I have

```
Cov(B, AS) = E[B * AS] - E[B]E[AS]

E[AS] = Cov(A, S) + E[A]E[S]

Cov(B, AS) = E[B * A * S] - E[B](Cov(A,S) + E[A]E[S]) = E[B * A * S] - E[B]*Cov(A,S) - E[B]E[A]E[S]
```

I have known that `Cov(A,S) > 0`, and `E[A]`, `E[B]` and`E[S]` are all greater than zero.

With this, I cannot decide the sign of Cov(B,AS). Is this right?

Comment: What do you mean with solve? There is nothing to solve. You mean evaluate? And what are the distributions of your RVs?

Comment: Thanks. Edited.